# Styling a dynamic nested UL structure

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a nested UL structure that represents a folder tree which can grow very deep. I'm stuck at doing a simple :hover effect for the LI elements. The problem is that doing a li:hover won't work as it affects all the parent "li's" aswell. Usually I would have tried to apply the hover effect to a link element or something in the LI, to avoid parents taking the style aswell, but due to circumstances that's not an option now. I have a working solution by using javascript to place a class on the hovered LI and then style this class instead, but i'm really interested in seeing if there's actually a way of accomplishing this through pure css.

I imagine there may be a way of doing a very "hardcoded" css solution but i am more interested in a dynamic and clean one, since the structure can nest indefinitely.

Maybe there's some pseudo selector i'm not aware of? Note that it doesn't have to be IE<8 compatible

```
<ul>
    <li>
        This LI should not recieve the hover effect
        <ul>
            <li>
                A li:hover will place the effect on this LI, 
                but also the parent LI, since that element is
                also techincally being hovered.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No parent selector in CSS so not possible

Comment: You want to style the deepest nested li on hover?

Comment: What about `ul ul li:hover { /*...*/ }`?

Comment: I prefer `li li:hover` for brevity and ol vs ul agnosticism.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks not necessarily the deepest one, just affecting one at depth without affecting parents.

Comment: @morewry and kleinfreund, as i mention that is one "hardcoded" solution but not very effective when my UL tree reaches 10 levels or so..

Comment: @KristianSandström What do you mean? With that selector it shouldn't matter how deep you nest, it will catch all nested `li`s. Isn't what you want to have the first level to have style #1 and all nested levels to have style #2? That can be done with two selectors, two sets of properties, and infinitely nested HTML.  What am I missing?

Comment: @morewry the problem is that you can't isolate a specific level and apply the style to just that level. If you have a list that is 10 deep, and you hover the tenth level, your `li li:hover` will be applied to levels 2-10, instead of just 10

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that's what you wanted to do. Your original question sounded as if you only needed to distinguish between the first and nested levels.  If you're talking about siblings you can use nth-child.  For descendants, however, I believe there is no other way except to add onto the selector (li li li li li ul > li [6th]) to target an arbitrary depth excluding all others.  I'd rethink it from scratch if you have to do that for every level of a deeply nested list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure CSS then you will need to us parent, child, elements.

For the hover elements:

```
ul li:hover{
   "Style"
}
```

For the other elements:

```
ul li ul li{
    "Style"
}
```

Comment: as i mention in the post this isn't very pretty when your nested ul's can reach 10 or deeper :/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: I just reread your question, in which you state:

> "Usually I would have tried to apply the hover effect to a link
>   element or something in the LI, to avoid parents taking the style as
>   well, but due to circumstances that's not an option now."

If that is true, then the solution below is not viable for your circumstance, and you cannot achieve what you desire with pure CSS. *I've left my answer, however, as others who want to achieve this but can use a nested element may find it useful.*

---

### Pure CSS Only by Adding HTML

The only way you can possibly achieve something of what you seek by pure CSS is to add an extra element (like a `span`) within the `li` and perform the hover on that. I assume that whatever folder is being hovered, that folder alone is what you want to highlight. If so, [this fiddle illustrates what I am saying](http://jsfiddle.net/uJjsd/9/), using this code:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Folder 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Folder 1.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Folder 1.1.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span>Folder 1.1.1.1</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li span:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

Now, *if you want child folders to also highlight on hover of a parent folder*, then [perhaps this fiddle illustrates what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/uJjsd/11/) with this code change:

**CSS**

```
li span:hover,
li span:hover + ul span {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

They key point is to utilize the extra element to control the hover, whether of the item itself or any later generation elements that the hover should affect.

Comment: Indeed this is how it should be achieved if markup allows it. I guess we'll have to wait for some sort of CSS equivalent of "event.stopPropagation();" before this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear at all... but if you want to style nested `LI` when you are hovered the parent `LI` without styling the parent one...

Try this:

### CSS

```
ul li ul li {
    color: blue
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    color: red
}
```

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EHp3n/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and also it will confuse. Let me explain, when the user hover the city (India / China / UK), style should be applied to State and Country through CSS.

```
<ul>
  <li>India (Apply Style)
    <ul>
      <li>India State (Apply Style)
        <ul>
          <li>India City (On Hover)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>China
    <ul>
      <li>China State
        <ul>
          <li>China City</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>United Kingdom
    <ul>
      <li>UK State
        <ul>
          <li>UK City</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, or well, thats the problem. When the user hovers the City, it is only the city LI that should be affected by a style change and not the state or country.